# не срабатывает конструкция jquery iframe load

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, iframe, submit

```
    $("iframe[src*='formfree']").load(function() {
      $(this).contents().find('form.lt-form').submit(function() { 
          ym(60755020, 'reachGoal', 'besplatno');
          return true;
      });
    });
```

Есть форма, которая подгружается с другого сайта только при нажатии на кнопку. У формы нет id, поэтому ищу её по совпадению в URL. 
Пытаюсь отправить событие в Яндекс.Метрику при заполнении формы , но не срабатывает... (проверяю через `?_ym_debug=1`)
При этом `$(this).contents().find('form.lt-form')` находит элемент.

Comment: У вас есть ответ в вопросе `..которая подгружается с другого сайта`. Вы не можете прочитать iframe с другого сайта.

Comment: Так load как раз и должен читать iframe. И в консоли вполне читает

Comment: @theblackpost дай пример сайта